# IOS push notifications not working on react native using firebase and react-native-push-notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, react-native-ios

So i have tried to receive push notifications from firebase and react-native-push-notifications.[react-native-push-notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)
on android its work perfect.

my problem is only on IOS.
i have follow the [push-notification-ios](https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios) installation with no result.

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.3.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.7.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.32.2",
    "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.1",
    "react-native-mail": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^5.0.1",
    "react-native-restart": "^0.0.17",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.0.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^10.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.1",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.2.2",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "jest": "^26.2.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.61.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

appDelegate.m :

```
    #import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>



#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
#import <FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>
#import <FlipperKitLayoutPlugin/FlipperKitLayoutPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitUserDefaultsPlugin/FKUserDefaultsPlugin.h>
#import <FlipperKitNetworkPlugin/FlipperKitNetworkPlugin.h>
#import <SKIOSNetworkPlugin/SKIOSNetworkAdapter.h>
#import <FlipperKitReactPlugin/FlipperKitReactPlugin.h>

static void InitializeFlipper(UIApplication *application) {
  FlipperClient *client = [FlipperClient sharedClient];
  SKDescriptorMapper *layoutDescriptorMapper = [[SKDescriptorMapper alloc] initWithDefaults];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitLayoutPlugin alloc] initWithRootNode:application withDescriptorMapper:layoutDescriptorMapper]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FKUserDefaultsPlugin alloc] initWithSuiteName:nil]];
  [client addPlugin:[FlipperKitReactPlugin new]];
  [client addPlugin:[[FlipperKitNetworkPlugin alloc] initWithNetworkAdapter:[SKIOSNetworkAdapter new]]];
  [client start];
}
#endif

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  
  
#ifdef FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif

  
 
  
    [FIRApp configure];
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"NewSderotNet"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
   center.delegate = self;
  return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}
// Required for the register event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
}
// Required for the registrationError event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];
}
// IOS 10+ Required for localNotification event
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
  completionHandler();
}
// IOS 4-10 Required for the localNotification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}




- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end
```

appDelegate.h :

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UNUserNotificationCenter.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate,UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
        <string>co.il.feed-b.FeedBack</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>appName</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>acess</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>access</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>access</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

on app Identifier i have been selected push notifications and created

- Production SSL Certificate
- Development SSL Certificate

also add to signing & capabilities background modes :

- background fetch
- remote notifications

then upload the Certificate to my firebase console and try to send push notification on real device without any event trigger and no notification is display.

Answer (score 5):

You upload and APN key (.p8 file) to Firebase project.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3367?fbclid=IwAR3mf_0a-MRdWI90mDTOuQmWw1T9EtqiU_f3uVj0lY9cAOt9qtxlFBhzJAU#issuecomment-628963057

this solved my problem ! i have add the functions  to my code and its work! if someone had problems with this you welcome to send me a message

Answer (score -1):

To implement push notifications using Firebase, please use https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage. Just upload APN Key to firebase and Add capability to your xCode project.

It will work Perfectly!